# Configure Python3 path for local docker prerelease script

Tags: ros, ubuntu, pre-release, docker, ubuntu-trusty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Following the docker prerelease tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/regression_tests#How_do_I_setup_my_system_to_run_a_prerelease.3F), I see the following error. What am I possibly doing wrong?

```
$ env | grep PYTHONPATH
PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
['', '/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/FontTools', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/omniORB/COS', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']
n130s@kudu1:/tmp/prerelease_job$ sudo ./prerelease.sh 
Prerelease script
:
+ export PYTHONPATH=/tmp/prerelease_job/ros_buildfarm:
+ python3 -u /tmp/prerelease_job/ros_buildfarm/scripts/devel/run_devel_job.py --rosdistro-index-url https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index.yaml indigo default prerelease ubuntu trusty amd64 --distribution-repository-urls http://54.183.65.232/ubuntu/testing --distribution-repository-key-files /tmp/prerelease_job/keys/0.key --dockerfile-dir /tmp/prerelease_job/docker_generating_dockers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/prerelease_job/ros_buildfarm/scripts/devel/run_devel_job.py", line 20, in <module>
    from ros_buildfarm.templates import create_dockerfile
  File "/tmp/prerelease_job/ros_buildfarm/ros_buildfarm/templates/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from em import Interpreter
ImportError: No module named 'em'

$ locate empy -b
/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/empy.cmake
/opt/ros/jade/share/catkin/cmake/empy.cmake
/usr/bin/empy
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/empy-3.1.egg-info
/usr/share/doc/python-empy
/usr/share/man/man1/empy.1.gz
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-empy.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-empy.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-empy.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-empy.prerm
```

<s>(BTW I had to `sudo` the script. [PR is opened](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm/pull/88) for that.)</s>

Ubuntu 14.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212786/configure-python3-path-for-local-docker-prerelease-script/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2015-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apparently the template evaluation still uses Python3 to run by default, so just make sure you have python3 and python3-empy installed. I'll update the wiki to include this workaround. Ultimately the correct solution would be to have those scripts use Python2 when the Python2 version of ros_buildfarm is installed.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1